# Select multiple images from android gallery using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose

How can I select multiple images from gallery using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()` in Jetpack Compose? It's `onResult` callback returns only one `Uri`

I'm using Compose on a project where users can upload multiple files at the same time. But I can't seem to find anything about it on the internet.

There was `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)` to be used with `startActivityForResult()`. Does it have something equivalent in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: This is not really tied to Compose, but rather to whatever contract you are using. `GetMultipleContents` or `OpenMultipleDocuments` on `ActivityResultContracts` seem like what you would want -- what are you using?

Comment: Oh. GetMultipleContents gives back a MutableList<Uri>. That was it. Thanks a lot!